# Create Well-Being Latent Variable in Lavaan from Depression/Anxiety Questionnaire

Tags: r, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

I'm building a structural equation model that incorporates 4 latent variables: physical lifestyle, social lifestyle, trauma score, and the DV (well-being).

We have a 7 question survey of just well-being, but I think it would be more sound (less measurement error) to cull three surveys of well-being, depression, and anxiety to make them into a latent dependent variable. I received the warning that the covariance matrix was not positive definite when just using the scaled scores from the surveys, so I decided to actually incorporate the questions from the surveys themselves. However, when I do this and then look at modification indices I receive an output that suggests that the residuals are not currently correlated, when I thought that that was the default for any latent variable, which is why I am wondering whether I am specifying the well-being latent variable correctly (whether it's just a matter of adding in all questions that will ultimately comprise this latent variable).

Below is the entire model. The latent variable "well-being" currently only has questions from the phq 9, Depression Survey; and the General Anxiety Survey (but will also be adding in the well-being survey). I've added the output for the modification indices below that.

I've included some data here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AX50DFNik30Qsyiyp6XnPMETNfVXK83r/view?usp=sharing

Thanks much!

```
fit.latent_wb <- '
  #factor loadings; measurement model portion
  pl =~ exercisescore + mindfulnessscore + promistscore
  sl =~ family_support + friendshipcount + friendshipnet +
        sense_of_community + sesscore + ethnicity
  trauma =~ neglectscore + abusescore + exposure + family_support + age
   wb =~ phq9_1 + phq9_2 + phq9_3 + phq9_4 + phq9_5 + phq9_6 +
         phq9_7 + phq9_8 + phq9_9 + gad7_1 + gad7_2 + gad7_3 + gad7_4 +
         gad7_5+ gad7_6+ gad7_7

  #regressions: structural model
  wb ~ age + gender + ethnicity + sesscore + resiliencescore + 
       pl + emotionalsupportscore + trauma
  resiliencescore ~ age + sesscore + emotionalsupportscore + sl
  emotionalsupportscore ~ sl + gender

friendshipnet~~age
exercisescore~~sense_of_community
'
fit.latent_wb <- sem(fit.latent_wb, data = total, meanstructure = TRUE, std.lv = TRUE)
summary(fit.latent_wb, fit.measures = TRUE,standardized = TRUE, rsquare = TRUE, estimates = FALSE)
```

Output for Mod Indices:

[image]

Comment: Which matrix wasn't positive definite?

Comment: Your wb is a very ambitious latent variable. One of these scales at a time rarely fits a model with a single latent variable.

Comment: Hi, thanks...the matrix combining scaled scores of depression and anxiety into a latent variable. Yeah, I've also heard that sometimes people break the depression questionnaire itself into separate latent variables. I guess my thought is that if we really want to evaluate well-being, we should include the information we have on one's mental health.

Comment: Do you think there is a better approach? Also, I don't understand why it would be telling me to correlate residuals among items that are all included in a latent variable...aren't these residuals already correlated?

Comment: No, residuals aren't correlated, that's kind of the point of CFA. The partial correlation of the variables (i.e. the correlations of the residuals) are zero, controlling for the latent variable. The reason the indicators correlated is because they have a common cause.

Comment: It looks from that snippet like all of the gad residuals want to correlate with each other, and all of your phq variables want to correlate with each other. You could try a bifactor model, or a second order model, but I suspect that's going to be far more complex than you want.

Comment: I'd be tempted to calculate a summed score of GAD, PHQ and use those as indicators of a latent variable. You might also try parcels.

Comment: What's your sample size?

Comment: Sample size is ~ 360. Re your suggestion of summed scores of GAD and PHQ--if I understand you correctly, that was my original thought, which yielded a non-positive definite matrix.

Comment: Which matrix was non-positive definite?

Comment: So when I add the scaled scores of well-being, anxiety, and depression to create a latent variable, I receive the following warning (I was receiving a not-positive definite warning for just adding anxiety and depression but I am no longer receiving that warning) : ```Warning message:
In lav_model_vcov(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavsamplestats = lavsamplestats,  :
  lavaan WARNING:
    Could not compute standard errors! The information matrix could
    not be inverted. This may be a symptom that the model is not
    identified.```

Comment: Model non-identification can be complex. Either your model is wrongly specified, or your model does not match your data.

Comment: Just a follow-up question: if anxiety and depression scale scores are not significant indicator variables (non-significant p-values) of the well-being latent variable, is that essentially saying that these indicator variables don't load well onto latent variable (overall model fit is good), which would seem strange since well-being latent variable is then the main endogenous variable.

Comment: Yeah, that would be strange.

Comment: How would you get the SEs for the standardized estimates (std.all) in Lavaan...I wasn't able to find that in a search)?

Comment: Not sure, that's not something I'm usually interested in.

Comment: Hi Jeremy: I've been reading your paper: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4616155/ trying to figure out an answer to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65896425/sem-structural-equation-model-moderated-mediation-but-returns-with-informatio I can't find a lot out there on moderated mediation in R. Could you take a look at the question? It looks like you were also correlating residuals of the terms in your interaction respect ~~ maleXResp and male ~~ maleXResp (no page numbers but in "Evaluating moderated mediation" section). Thanks much!